# python wrapper function without specifying arguments twice

Tags: python, decorator, functools

I have a function that does some data processing, for example:

```py
from typing import Optional

from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

def standard_date_formatter(
    df: DataFrame,
    prev_name: str,
    prev_fmt: str,
    next_name: Optional[str] = None,
    next_fmt: str = "yyyy-MM-dd"
):
    # data transformation implementation here
    pass
```

I have another function which verifies parameters, which I want to be a wrapper in order to use it with other data transformation functions I write. However, I've had to repeat the parameters in the wrapper. Right now I have

```py
from functools import wraps

import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.types import DateType, StringType

def validate_old_new(fn):
    @wraps(fn)
    def wrapper(
        df: DataFrame,
        prev_name: str,
        prev_format: str,
        next_name: Optional[str] = None,
        next_format: str = "yyyy-MM-dd",
    ):
        try:
            prev_type = df.schema[prev_name].dataType
        except KeyError:
            raise ValueError("Column to be converted does not exist.")

        if prev_type not in (StringType(), DateType()):
            raise AttributeError(
                "Column to be converted must be StringType or DateType"
            )

        if not next_name:
            next_name = prev_name

        df_to_format = (
            df
            if prev_type == StringType()
            else df.withColumn(prev_name, f.col(prev_name).cast(StringType()))
        )

        return fn(df_to_format, prev_name, prev_format, next_name, next_format)

    return wrapper

@validate_old_new
def date_formatter(...) # as above
```

Is there a way to avoid duplicating the parameters in the wrapper? If not, is there a recommended, pythonic way to avoid duplicating parameters in a "helper function" (in my case the data transformation function)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `*args` and `**kwargs` to avoid duplicate parameter definitions, [read more](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/args_and_kwargs.html).

```py
import functools

def validate_old_new(fn):
    @functools.wraps(fn)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        df = args[0]
        next_name = kwargs.get('next_name')
        # Validation process...
        
        return fn(...)

    return wrapper


@validate_old_new
def date_formatter(
    df: DataFrame,
    prev_name: str,
    prev_format: str,
    next_name: Optional[str] = None,
    next_format: str = "yyyy-MM-dd",
):
    pass

# or 

@validate_old_new
def date_formatter(*args, **kwargs):
    pass
```

Comment: moreover, one should use `functools.wraps` on the wrapper as well, in order for the static-checking tools to be able to find their way,